# what about a debating stackexchange?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, allowed-topics

I would love a debating site from stackexchange. If there is one already can you point it out?
That would be very addicting. A site that has subcategories, like debate philosophy, debate history, social issues, etc...

Thanks :)

Comment: Why not take a look at the SE incubation area, area51.stackexchange.com?

Comment: isn't that what the chat feature is for? http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/538/the-symposium

Comment: is not very precise. For example, I used the math chat room today to ask a mathematical question and got responses like: I am not good with numbers!

Comment: This sounds like just about every other philosophy forum on the internet. A big reason why I don't frequent them....